# Webserver/Minecraft server on same IP address

Tags: apache2, server, webserver, windows

Here's what's going on. I have a 2019 windows server, and on it Im running a webserver (apache2), and multiple Minecraft servers. I have a domain with multiple subdomains for each Minecraft server instance and the webserver. They're all in my domain DNS settings with both A and SRV records. That works all fine and dandy.

Let's say I have two Minecraft servers, running on different ports. First server is mc.domain.com, second is mc2.domain.com. Then for my webserver, it's site.domain.com. I can use each Minecraft domain and it connects to the corresponding server perfectly fine. I go to my web browser and put in site.domain.com and it brings me to that. Heres the issue, since this is all running on one machine and one IP, if I put mc.domain.com or mc2.domain.com in my web browser, it also points to site.domain.com.

How can I only allow site.domain.com to bring me to my webserver and not any other subdomain? Please don't close this and say duplicate and send me to a general "how to forward a Minecraft server" because that isn't my issue. Thank you.

Comment: From your original question, I didn't see that you were running Apache.   That makes it easier.  You can skip down to the configuring virtual hosts for Apache section of the answer.

Comment: Yeah that's my bad, I said it more specific when i originally said "Multicraft" but it uses Apache2 to host it I believe. I tried messing around with vhosts but it's a bit more complicated the way Multicraft sets it all up. I don't have the normal Apache panel that you'd see with XAMPP. I dont remember how I changed the vhosts conf file but even after that it didn't fix my issue. I can take a look tonight when I'm out of work and share what I changed. From other research I was thinking maybe having to set up a proxy to direct but I'm not 100% sure. This is mostly new to me. Thanks